# Citrix XenApp Deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, xenapp

I am new to Citrix and am thinking of proposing a Citrix solution for our home and remote office workers. My question is regarding deployment and licensing. To allow the clients to have remote application deployment via Citrix XenApp do we need to buy anything in addition to the Citrix XenApp and Windows Server 2008? Is there additional Citrix software/licensing that is required? Do we need to purchase Terminal Server licensing or is this inclusive with Windows Server 2008 (for TS Server side) and Windows XP/Vista/7 (for TS client licensing)? Do I need Citrix Presentation Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to purchase XenApp licenses (which are concurrent), and also Remote Desktop licenses (which are normally per user or per device). You may need an RDP External Connector licenses for users coming in from outside the network. I recommend doing lots of research on licensing and contacting a professional to make sure you are correctly covered.

To cut down on the costs and complexities, I would also look into Windows Server 2008 R2's RemoteApp and RD Web Access if you haven't, since it has 90% of the features that Citrix XenApp has.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I am looking to learn as much as I can before contacting anyone regarding this to ensure that we have the right solution. Can you point point me in the right direction regarding Win 2008 R2 Remote App?

Comment: Microsoft has this page for the 2008 version (very similar to R2): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730673(WS.10).aspx
Here is another site with pictures :) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_RemoteApps_on_Windows_Server_2008_R2

Answer (score 1):

It really all depends on your deployment - fundamentally Citrix sits on top of Server 200x Terminal Services and that's that. However, there's lots more such as web interface servers, secure gateways, access gateways etc that you may wish to consider. Thing is, all of these things depend very much on your environment, where you want people to access from and what you want them to do once they're there.

Plus it gets more complicated by the virtue that XenApp 5 goes on 2008, and XenApp 6 goes on R2.

I'm a big Citrix advocate, but I agree with @KJ-SRS that it's something you should chat over with a consultancy. They have a huge amount of products to answer pretty much any business need, but It's a lot of money to spend on going gung ho. Citrix Presentation Server was re branded as XenApp, by the way - so they're sort of the same product.

I don't think you're going to be able to get the indepth insight you need over the internet. I certainly couldn't give it to you without taking a look at your environment and what you do.